# Simplifying fractions

Tags: c

I have compiled a database for rational numbers. Integers are used to represent the numerator and denominator of rational numbers. Subtractions, additions, multiplications, and divisions can be performed. However, I'm not getting simplified answers after performing a task. In addition, the answer for `1/2-1/2` is `0/4`, which is quite weird.

My code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int gcd(int a, int b) {
    if (a == 0)
        return b;
    return gcd(b % a, a);
}

int addFraction(int n1, int d1, int n2, int d2, int d3, int n3) { //Add
    d3 = gcd(d1, d2);
    d3 = (d1 * d2) / d3;
    n3 = (n1) * (d3 / d1) + (n2) * (d3 / d2);
    printf("\n %d/%d + %d/%d \t = \t %d/%d\n", n1, d1,n2, d2, n3, d3);
    return 0;
}

int subFraction(int n1, int d1, int n2, int d2, int d3, int n3) { //Subtract
    d3 = d1 * d2;
    n3 = (n1 * d2 - n2 * d1);
    printf("\n %d/%d - %d/%d \t = \t %d/%d\n", n1, d1, n2, d2, n3, d3);
    return 0;
}

int mulFraction(int n1, int d1, int n2, int d2, int d3, int n3) { //Multiply
    n3 = n1 * n2;
    d3 = d1 * d2;
    printf("\n %d/%d * %d/%d \t = \t %d/%d\n", n1, d1, n2, d2, n3, d3);
    return 0;
}

int divFraction(int n1, int d1, int n2, int d2, int d3, int n3) { //division
    n3 = n1 * d2;
    d3 = d1 * n2;
    printf("\n %d/%d / %d/%d \t = \t %d/%d\n", n1, d1, n2, d2, n3, d3);
    return 0;
}

int main() {
    int n1, d1, n2, d2, d3 = 0, n3 = 0;
    printf("\n Enter the values of numerator 1 and denominator 1: ");
    scanf("%d %d", &n1, &d1);
    printf("\n Enter the values of numerator 2 and denominator 2: ");
    scanf("%d %d", &n2, &d2);
    addFraction(n1, d1, n2, d2, d3, n3); //calling the function to perform addition of rational values
    subFraction(n1, d1, n2, d2, d3, n3); //calling the function to perform subtraction of rational values
    mulFraction(n1, d1, n2, d2, d3, n3); //calling the function to perform multiplication of rational values
    divFraction(n1, d1, n2, d2, d3, n3); //calling the function to perform division of rational values
    return 0;
}
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: please never post images of text instead of text

Comment: Anyway, why are you expecting simplified answers? Nothing in your code performs simplification.

Comment: I have removed it, thank you for the heads up.

Comment: @EvelynWein Function arguments are passed by value in C. None of your functions modify `n3, d3` so the results are not returned to the caller.

Comment: You are right, please allow me to edit my code.

Comment: Pleas indent your code properly. Are the samples in your learning material indented like this?

Comment: If your editor can't indent code, run it through `clang-format`, GNU `indent`, or another similar tool to make it readable.

Comment: You need a `gcd(n3, d3)` function to find a divisor to reduce the resultant fractions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are multiple problems in your code:

- the functions should take pointers to the result numerator and denominator.
- you should reduce the resulting fraction after computing its components

Here is a modified version:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int gcd(int a, int b) {
    if (a == 0)
        return b;
    return gcd(b % a, a);
}

void reduce(int n, int d, int *np, int *dp) {
    int dd = gcd(n, d);
    *np = n / dd;
    *dp = n / dd;
}

int addFraction(int n1, int d1, int n2, int d2, int *n3, int *d3) {
    reduce(n1 * d2 + n2 * d1, d1 * d2, n3, d3);
    printf("%d/%d + %d/%d \t = \t %d/%d\n", n1, d1, n2, d2, *n3, *d3);
    return 0;
}

int subFraction(int n1, int d1, int n2, int d2, int *n3, int *d3) {
    reduce(n1 * d2 - n2 * d1, d1 * d2, n3, d3);
    printf("%d/%d - %d/%d \t = \t %d/%d\n", n1, d1, n2, d2, *n3, *d3);
    return 0;
}

int mulFraction(int n1, int d1, int n2, int d2, int *n3, int *d3) {
    reduce(n1 * n2, d1 * d2, n3, d3);
    printf("%d/%d * %d/%d \t = \t %d/%d\n", n1, d1, n2, d2, *n3, *d3);
    return 0;
}

int divFraction(int n1, int d1, int n2, int d2, int *n3, int *d3) {
    reduce(n1 * d2, d1 * n2, n3, d3);
    printf("%d/%d / %d/%d \t = \t %d/%d\n", n1, d1, n2, d2, *n3, *d3);
    return 0;
}

int main() {
    int n1, d1, n2, d2, d3, n3;
    printf("Enter the values of numerator 1 and denominator 1: ");
    if (scanf("%d %d", &n1, &d1) != 2)
        return 1;
    printf("\n");
    printf("Enter the values of numerator 2 and denominator 2: ");
    if (scanf("%d %d", &n2, &d2) != 2)
        return 1;
    printf("\n");
    addFraction(n1, d1, n2, d2, &n3, &d3);
    subFraction(n1, d1, n2, d2, &n3, &d3);
    mulFraction(n1, d1, n2, d2, &n3, &d3);
    divFraction(n1, d1, n2, d2, &n3, &d3);
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use your *gcd* function on the result, for instance by defining a function which prints a fraction in a simplified form:

```
void printFraction(int numerator, int denominator)
{
    int d = gcd(numerator, denominator);
    int p = numerator / d;
    int q = denominator / d;
    printf("%d", p);
    if (q != 1) {
        printf("/%d", q);
    }
}
```

You also need to make sure that calls to *scanf* are successful and that no denominator is zero.